# Using OAuth in kivy?

Tags: android, python, oauth, kivy

I'm trying to use OAuth (Authorization Code Flow) in a kivy App. Because of that I want that my app is started from the browser using a special scheme, eg. myappscheme://dosomething. So I have added an intent-filter to my app:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="myappscheme" android:host="dosomething" />
</intent-filter>
```

Now my app starts when a redirect from a webserver is send to myappscheme://dosomething. But I have no idea how to retrieve the url parameters that are send. I have found that for Java: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html#HandleIntent but I do not know how to use it in kivy.

Maybe someone can help with that or knows an example for oauth and kivy?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kivy has some built in intend handling code, as described [here](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/old_toolchain/android/#module-android.activity). You can bind functions to be called when a new intent is received.

You can also look at how this is implemented in python-for-android to see how to extend it if you need to.

Comment: The link is broken :(

Comment: I've fixed the link, but this answer is now out of date and applies only to the old (unsupported) python-for-android toolchain. I'm not sure to what extent the same thing works with the new one, I don't think it's been explicitly added as a feature yet.